# CloudKit authentication Login / Password

Tags: ios, authentication, parse-platform, cloudkit

Here is my problem, I built an application using Parse solution. In this application I used the basic authencation of Parse. After Parse death I need to migrate.

I would like to implement an authentication with the CloudKit solution, but I'm not sure that it's a good pratice. I understood that the Cloudkit basic authentication was based on the user apple account. But I need to had an authentication with login/password.

There is no field of kind "password" like in Parse, so I don't know how to stock the password in my table Users in a secure Way. And I'm not sure that save the password in the public section is secure.

I would like to know if there are good practices to implement basic authentication in CloudKit (Login/Password)?

Thanks in advance for you help ;)

PS: Other solution should be to move to firebase, but I prefer the logic of CloudKit for the moment.

Answer (score 7):

To manage login/passwords with CloudKit, without backend login code, but letting the user sign in from another location (web app, android app, etc. using the recently introduced Cloudkit server-key access), you need to manage the login logic inside the app:

Workflow:

A. User Sign up

1. Create a "users" container in the public database in Cloudkit Dashboard.
2. When user types a password when signing up, encrypt the password.
3. Make a request to the "users" container if username/email already exists. If it does, warn the user. If not, continue the process.
4. Upload the email/username and encrypted password on the public "users" container in Cloudkit. Also include the user's iCloudId.

B. User Sign In

1. When user types its username/email and password, query the "users" encrypted password using the username/email. If the request is nil, it means that this username/email does not exist in the database.
2. If the database returns the encrypted password, decrypt it in the app and compare it with the password that the user typed in the login form. If they do not match, warn the user that the passwords do not match.

C. User forgot password

- In order for the user to change the password, the user must be logged in to its iCLoud Account in order to compare that the iCloudId of the account requesting the password change is equal to the iCLoudId of the user saved in CloudKit.
- Alternatively, you can ask for security questions to the user when he signs up, and then check for these when user requests password change.

This is not an advised solution (in terms of scalability) but I believe it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

When you choose CloudKit, you have to use Apple's iCloud authentication and you can't store the user's password.

But you can build an extra authentication layer. When an user is logged in with iCloud you can ask him to choose a password, which you can store in the a private (!) record type (with a reference to the iCloud user).

This way, a user need to login with iCloud first and then enter the app specific password in your app.

Comment: Thanks for your response, what I didn't specify is that my app is for an association, and they need to have control on users, it's the association that create user in backend there is no possibility to create account if you are not parte of the project. Cloudkit is perhaps not the solution to my problem.

Comment: you could let them enter a username plus password. Then first check in your backend system if it's OK, then if it's ok, connect it to the iCloud user (by saving user name plus password hash and iCloud ID in a separate user recordType). After that it's enough for the user to be loged in into iCloud. His iCloud account is connected to his account in the backend system.

Comment: I understand your answer , but my problem is that I don't have backend system, It was managed by parse. So I was looking for replacement of parse. In my case think that CloudKit can't do this job, because of this authentication. I'm looking in the firebase direction. Thanks a lot for your help